# firebase / google cloud storage getFiles works fine but .upload or .file do not

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, actions-on-google

I've firebase app with actions on google and google cloud storage.
When I do bucket.getFiles() it lists me the files, this works fine.
But when I do .upload or .file I get the following error:

```
ApiError: Error during request.
        at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:193:32)
        at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:137:18)
        at /user_code/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:502:12
        at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:195:7)
        at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
      code: undefined,
      errors: undefined,
      response: undefined,
      message: 'Error during request.'
```

This is my code:

```
'use strict';

const App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase');

const pdfkit = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');

var config = {
...
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var gcloud = require('google-cloud');

// Enable Storage
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: ...,
  keyFilename: ...
});

// Reference bucket
var bucket = gcs.bucket("gs://.../");

//action / intent
const NAME_ACTION = 'make_name';

exports.sillyNameMaker = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new App({request, response});

  //makename function
  function makeName (app) {

      //this does not work
      var doc = new pdfkit;
      const filename = 'output.pdf';
      const file = bucket.file(filename);
      const stream = file.createWriteStream({resumable: false});

      doc.pipe(stream);
      doc.fontSize(25).text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);
      doc.end();

      //this works
      bucket.getFiles()
        .then(results => {
          const files = results[0];
          console.log('Files:');
          files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file.name);
          })
          return results
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("error in get files: ",err));

      //this works not
      bucket.upload('./test.txt')
        .catch((err) => console.log("Error in upload file: ",err));
  }


  //map intent names to functions
  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(NAME_ACTION, makeName);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

I there a difference between the requests regarding permissions? Or do I need to enable something in google actions?

Answer (score 0):

The keyfile you're using to initialize your Storage client is linked to a service account on your project. That service account may indeed have enough permissions to list files in a bucket but not to upload files. See the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) for details on IAM permissions related to Cloud Storage.

The service account you use may have the `storage.objectViewer` role, which allows to list the objects in a bucket but not to create/upload them. Try granting it a broader role, like `storage.admin`, to verify it's working.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i already changed to google drive to store the files.